# replacing ls command in a bash script

Tags: bash

Everybody says it is [bad, bad, very bad to use ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) to parse. This is a script that will pick out a log file. I don't want to glob the whole directory, $1 is the name of the file I want to look at, and of those files, I only want to see the last two. How do I do this without using ls ?

```
for i in $(ls -ltr ~/logs/autosys/*${1}* | tail -2) ; do
    if [[ ${i} =~ ".out" ]] ; then
    tailpath=$(echo ${i%.*} | awk '{print $9}')
    fi
done
```

Comment: I don't understand what this code is supposed to do.

Comment: I think it's "take the two newest files in `~/logs/autosys` with names containing `$1`, then do something with them".

Comment: If you want to compare by last modification time and can't use the filename: [BashFAQ/003](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003)

Comment: @Benjamin - you are correct - that is what the snippet does  - it is part of something larger

Comment: `ls -t  | head -n2` will give you just the filename, you don't need to parse the `ls` output.

Comment: here's a good explanation about why it is "bad": http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you want

```
logfile=$(stat -c "%Y:%n" ~/logs/autosys/*"$1"*.out | sort -t: -k1,1n | tail -1 | cut -d: -f2-)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `tail -2` (the *two* latest ones, as per question)?

Comment: The logic of that loop is odd. The variable is set each tie through, so only the last iteration counts

Comment: I think it's incorrect in the code in the question, just pointing out that the text says "last *two*".

Comment: It appears that the OP wants the ".out" file that is in the last two. I'm short-circuiting that

Answer (score 1):

Without using `ls`, you would iterate over the files unconditionally, calling `stat` on each one, and keeping track of the two newest files yourself.

```
t0=0
t1=0

for i in ~/logs/autosys/*"${1}"*; do
    # Assuming GNU stat; syntax for other implementations may vary
    t=$(stat -c "%Y" "$i")
    if (( t > t0 )); then
        f1=$f0
        f0=$i
        t1=$t0
        t0=$t
    elif (( t > t1 )); then
        t1=$t
        f1=$i
    fi
done
```

Now `$f0` and `$f1` contain the names of the two newest files.

The fact is, `bash` isn't really suited for doing this task easily and efficiently. (The `bash` distribution does contain a built-in `stat` command, but it doesn't seem to be commonly installed.)

`zsh`, on the other hand, makes this task rather easy:

```
% files=(~/logs/autosys/*${1}*(Om[-2,-1]))
```

The glob qualifiers `Om` and `[-2,-1]` sort by modification date and limit the match to the last two elements, respectively. (`(om[1,2])` also works.)